# document.cookie returns only PHPSESSID=*random number*

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I'm trying to get a cookie I have set but all I'm getting is the PHPSESSID.

I set my cookie in a separate PHP page with:

```
setcookie("username", $sentname, time()+(60*60*24*30),NULL,NULL,NULL,false);
```

I can then find it through firefox settings.

When I try to access it using JavaScript on a different page I use:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        var cookie = document.cookie;

        alert(cookie);
        });

</script>
```

which then returns:

```
PHPSESSID=gvjsgfd8etlbdq43lndni3o0g4
```

It should return all the cookies, only "username" so far, I have set in a key paired string. I tried using the jquery plugin for cookies and it returned the same thing. I also couldn't find this problem elsewhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I should delete the question but one of the related links gave me the answer.

The cookie path must be set to '/' to be accessible from all subdomains. so I changed it too:

```
setcookie("username", $sentname, time()+(60*60*24*30),'/',NULL,NULL,false);
```

which gives me:

```
PHPSESSID=gvjsgfd8etlbdq43lndni3o0g4; username=asdf
```